# How to set up the app icons for a MonoDroid project?

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm making an app for Android and with the template I see a folder called Resources/Drawable/Icon.png

But if you create a native app with Eclipse you see that several sizes of icons can be configured for different screen sizes.

How can we do that in MonoDroid?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Resource folder on Mono for Android is mimicking the one on Android. So in order to create resource for different sizes of screens, you just create the folders according to which sizes of icons you want to put in them.

Your folder structure could end up looking like this:

```
|- Resources
    |- Drawable
        Icon.png
    |- Drawable-ldpi
        Icon.png
    |- Drawable-mdpi
        Icon.png
    |- Drawable-hdpi
        Icon.png
    |- Drawable-xhdpi
        Icon.png
```

And have the Icon.png files in different sizes according to the folder densities. The same principle goes for layouts as well. You can read more about this in the [Android documentation for supporting multiple screen sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).